# Algorithms: Majority element

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x

I am writing a divide-and-conquer solution to the majority element problem, in which it must output 1 if there is an element in a sequence of n integers that appears more than n/2 times or 0 otherwise. My code works perfectly for any test case I can think of, but the grading system keeps saying that it provides wrong answer for a test case.

```
n = int(input())
array = input().split()
for i in range(n):
    array[i] = int(array[i])
def merge(alist, blist):
    a = len(alist)
    b = len(blist)
    n = a + b
    result = []
    for i in range(n):
        if len(alist) > 0 and len(blist) > 0:
            if alist[0] < blist[0]:
                result.append(alist[0])
                alist.pop(0)
            else:
                result.append(blist[0])
                blist.pop(0)
        elif len(alist) == 0:
            result.extend(blist)
        elif len(blist) == 0:
            result.extend(alist)
    return result
def mergesort(numbers):
    if len(numbers) > 1:
        n = len(numbers)
        alist = numbers[:(n//2)]
        blist = numbers[(n//2):]
        alist = mergesort(alist)
        blist = mergesort(blist)
        numbers = merge(alist, blist)
    return numbers
array = mergesort(array)
key = array[n//2]
count = 0
for i in range(n):
    if array[i] == key:
        count += 1
if count > (n//2):
    print(1)
else:
    print(0)
```

Could anyone show me the error in my code?

Comment: Can you provide the problematic test case?

Comment: Why reimplement `sorted`? _Any_ Python implementation of generalized sort will run _much_ slower than the built-in? Is it a restriction of the assignment? What other restrictions are there?

Comment: @Nurzhan: that is the problem. They just said that my code failed in a test case but didnt provide that test case.

Comment: @ShadowRanger : It is an algorithm assignment. I am trying to better understand the divide-and-conquer technique by building my own sorting function.

Comment: So to be clear, are you _required_ to write your own sorting function? Or are you only supposed to be building the majority element part of the problem? Seems like if you're trying to find the problem, maybe you want to start by implementing the majority element part with built-in `sorted`, then reimplementing a drop in replacement for `sorted` later once you've got the majority element algorithm worked out.

Comment: @ShadowRanger : thank you. It works with the built-in sorted, so it seems there is problem about my sorting function.

Comment: @Giantonia: I see one thing that's almost certainly wrong. When you exhaust the `alist` or `blist`, you `extend` with the other one. But you don't terminate the loop or empty the `list` you just copied from. So you'll `extend` with the same values multiple times.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Wow it works perfectly now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40144454/algorithms-majority-element/40145251#comment67559245_40144454) to answer:

In the `merge` function, when handling the case of one `list` being exhausted, the other `list` is added to the end of the combined `list` with `extend`, but the loop is not terminated, and the non-empty `list` is not cleared, so if the terminal `extend` occurs early, the remainder of the non-empty `list` is repeated multiple times. Change the loop to the following, with a terminal case that `extend`s the remaining `list` (additional cleanups added to reduce code length):

```
# Stop when first list exhausted, not after fixed repetitions
while alist and blist:
    if alist[0] < blist[0]:
        result.append(alist.pop(0))
    else:
        result.append(blist.pop(0))

# Only one will have contents, simpler to just unconditionally extend,
# rather than test and extend, since extending with empty list is harmless
result += alist
result += blist
```

Side-note: `pop(0)` is `O(n)` on `list`s, while `.pop()` is `O(1)`. For large sorts, the following would be more efficient:

```
# Reverse once up front, so you can pop from right, not left
alist.reverse()
blist.reverse()

# Stop when first list exhausted, not after fixed repetitions
while alist and blist:
    if alist[-1] < blist[-1]:
        result.append(alist.pop())
    else:
        result.append(blist.pop())

# Only one will have contents, simpler to just unconditionally extend,
# rather than test and extend, since extending with empty list is harmless
result += alist[::-1]
result += blist[::-1]
```